# Состояние кнопки в контекстном меню в трее

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне с помощью PyQt5 нужно создать кнопку на подобие тех, что на картинке

[image]

Когда на неё нажимаешь, она либо показывает галочку, либо убирает

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#checkable-prop

Comment: Хотя вам уже теоретически дали ответ, в указанной выше ссылке описаны свойства, которые вам надо применить. Но если у вас возникнут трудности с практической реализацией, опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример и вам помогут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил кнопке свойство `isCheckable = True`